# My jQuery functions break each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

When adding two or more functions in my jquery script file the function/s stops working.

It's working perfectly fine when I've only written one function. But when I'm adding a second one both of them stops working.

I've added a JSFiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/b966e9ae/

```js
function accordion() {
 $('.content').accordion({active: 'false', collapsible: 'true'});
}

function slide() {
 $('#btnClick').click(function(){
  $('.box').toggle('slide', {direction: 'left', 1000});
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 accordion();
 slide();
});
```

```css
div.box {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: red;
}

button#btnClick {
 position: absolute;
 top: 200px;
 left: 500px;
}

h1 {
 background-color: #bbb;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 outline-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <h1>Rubrik 1</h1>
   <div class="info">
    <p>Detta är lite info</p>
    <ul>
     <li>Info 1</li>
     <li>Info 2</li>
     <li>Info 3</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   
   <h1>Rubrik 2</h1>
   <div class="info">
    <ul>
     <li>Sked</li>
     <li>2xTomater</li>
     <li>1xKryddmått</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   
   <h1>Rubrik 3</h1>
   <div class="info">
    <p>Detta</p>
    <p>är</p>
    <p>Schysst!</p>
   </div>
   
   <h1>Rubrik 4</h1>
   <div class="info">
    <p>Detta</p>
    <p>är</p>
    <p>Schysst!</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
   
  </div>
  
  <button id="btnClick">Click me</button>
```

Comment: The `slide()` function, as posted, has a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
$('#btnClick').click(function(){
    $('.box').toggle('slide', {direction: 'left', 1000});
                                                ^                                                   
});
```

It should be:

```
$('#btnClick').click(function(){
    $('.box').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'left'
    }, 1000);                                                    ^                                                   
});
```

Comment: Gah!
This "problem" has caused me a lot of troubleshooting and realizing that I caused it myself is so annoying! Blinded by my own code... Of course it should be as you've shown above. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Turlestew If you check in the JavaScript console (F12) then you can usually identify these types of errors very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.box').toggle('slide', {direction: 'left', 1000});
```

this is throwing an error (check your console).

It has to be:

```
$('.box').toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/saw3jox2/)**